# Signing up User with email and password gives No AppCheckProvider installed

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase as my backend. I am signin user with email and password.

First i am creating user with email and password like this :

```
try{
      await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
    }on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'weak-password') {
        print('The password provided is too weak.');
      } else if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
        print('The account already exists for that email.');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
```

Then signing in the user like this :

```
try{
      await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
    }on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
        print('No user found for that email.');
        // showErrorDialogBox(context, 'No user found for that email.');
      } else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
        // showErrorDialogBox(context, 'Wrong password provided for that user.');
        print('Wrong password provided for that user.');
      }
    }
```

But still getting these errors

```
E/StorageException( 9609): StorageException has occurred.
E/StorageException( 9609): User is not authenticated, please authenticate using Firebase Authentication and try again.
E/StorageException( 9609):  Code: -13020 HttpResult: 401
W/StorageUtil( 9609): Error getting App Check token; using placeholder token instead. Error: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: No AppCheckProvider installed.
W/NetworkRequest( 9609): no auth token for request
```

Comment: can you paste code for the auth object also? is registration working? have you checked whether the user is added in the authentication section or not?

Comment: auth is nothing else just instance of FirebaseAuth ```FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;``` Yes i get a user in authentication.

Comment: ok. i hope you have done these things but still reminder- 1. Added sha1- sha256,  2. added support email in firebase project setting.  3. enabled the sign in methods 4. make sure that inputs are correct email & password without extra spaces. you can do trim() if not

Comment: @DhananjayGavali everything is fine just getting this error ```E/StorageException(13437): StorageException has occurred.
E/StorageException(13437): User is not authenticated, please authenticate using Firebase Authentication and try again.
E/StorageException(13437):  Code: -13020 HttpResult: 401
E/StorageException(13437): The server has terminated the upload session 
Caused by: java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 401,    "message": "Firebase App Check token is invalid."  }}```

Comment: are you using storage. make sure that you have set read, write permission in storage

Comment: @DhananjayGavali they are set already ```rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```
How can i specify that only authenticated users can acess the storage ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was running the app on emulator, but when I run the app on the physical device, nothing happens. Don't know why it is happening, but it is happening only on emulators.